# Python; convert from .txt line with readline() to tuple

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, udp, tuples, requirements.txt

I'm making a client in python, the problem comes when I wanna use an ip and a port  (separated by a space) from a .txt file to use it for **.sendto(msg,(data))**

```
import socket
import sys
import os

sUDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

file = open("./file.txt")
data1 = file.readline()
msg = "hi"

sUDP.sendto(msg, (data1)) #THE ERROR
```

The ./file.txt contains:

127.0.0.1 40000

127.0.0.1 55000

I would like sUDP.sendto(msg, (data1)) to work properly or know how to convert the first read line in order to separate ip and port to make a tuple to make sendto work

This is the console when i want to compile:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cliente.py", line whatever, in 
    sUDP.sendto(msg, (data1)) #THE ERROR
TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str**

Thank you for all the people helping me! I gotta finish this work soon

**EDIT:** 
I discovered that using .split() I can make two separated strings using one with an space. The only thing I had to do is to convert the port to int using int(port) and we can make the tuple! By the way i there's a more efficient way of making tuples from the file.txt tell me thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> By the way i there's a more efficient way of making tuples from the file.txt tell me

Well, this is certainly not more efficient, because it's basically the same as you had to do - it's just combining the steps:

```
data1 = tuple(t(v) for t, v in zip([str, int], open("file.txt").readline().split()))
```

Answer (score -2):

Usage of tulple merely waste.
Just use sets inside a dictionary.

This will be the good opt

So just try with list and dictionaries